# Image Field Style URL from EntityMetadataWrapper?

Tags: media, entities

Does EntityMetadataWrapper support reading the URL of an image field for a specified image-style? I thought I had done this before but I can't find it documented anywhere or any code in the tests for EntityMetadataWrapper.